# kinetic js ipad scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, kineticjs

I previously had an HTML5 canvas based application that I recently converted to using Kinetic JS.  I was able to enable scrolling in desktop browsers and IOS by simply using overflow: auto on the encompassing div.  Since converting over to using Kinetic scrolling no longer functions on mobile/iPad devices.

I have tried working around this issue a few different ways though I am a bit stuck.  First I tried using touchscroll though for various reasons this didn't work for me (things did scroll though the library is causing other issues).  Next I tried adding the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch options to my div's style though this didn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a standard way of scrolling a Kinetic JS canvas that is larger than your viewable area/div?

Here is an example.  If you view the example on an IOS device (iPad, iPhone, etc) you will notice that the top canvas does not scroll within the div while the bottom one does.

http://jsfiddle.net/blueshirts/uERVq/26/

```
<!-- KineticJS canvase, won't scroll on IOS devices. -->
<div id="container" style="overflow: auto; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-    color: gray">
</div>

<br/>

<!-- Vanilla HTML5 Canvas, does scroll on IOS devices. -->
<div id="canvasContainer"
     style="width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: auto; background-color: red">
    <canvas id="vanillaCanvas"
            width="800" height="600">
    </canvas> 
</div>

// Create a stage instance that is larger than its parent div.
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 800,
    height: 600
});

// Create a layer.
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

// Add some text...
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    text: "KineticJS generated Canvas that won't scroll to IOS touches...",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    textFill: 'Black'                
});
layer.add(text);

// Add a rectangle to the layer so you can see if the content scrolls.
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    fill: "yellow",
    stroke: "black",
    strokeWidth: 7
});
layer.add(rect);

// Add the layer to the stage.
stage.add(layer);


// Create a "vanilla" canvas instance and draw the same rectangle on it.
var canvas = document.getElementById('vanillaCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.rect(50, 50, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();
```

Edit:

Could be wrong though seems to me that this issue is caused by the fact that Kinetic is registering for touchmove events (and others) in the Stage class.  In the handler it run's preventDefault which seems to stop mobile browsers from executing their default scroll behavior.  If "I" had registered for touchmove events this would probably be desirable.  Would be nice if Kinetic didn't register and handle events that I am not interested in.

```
 _touchmove: function(evt) {
     this._setUserPosition(evt);
     var dd = Kinetic.DD;
     evt.preventDefault();
```

I am able to demonstrate this issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/blueshirts/P9RaT/28/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a fundamental bug in Kinetic JS. Had I known this was the case I wouldn't have began using kinetic JS to embark on an ambitious project when it cant even do the fundamentals.

Due to no responses from any of the Kinetic Team I will be switching to a less buggy library like fabric.js.

Comment: Add an 'activate' / 'deactivate' button on the canvas. The deactivate  script would simply do something like check all items on the stage to see if they are 'listening', and if true, set them to 'wasListening' or some other holder variable, then set listening to false. The activate button checks all items on the stage for 'wasListening' then sets them to 'listening(true)'.

Comment: Or, have the whole stage 'not listening' unless the user activates specific controls on the stage. That way it will respond to typical scroll touch events.

Comment: also, are you saying Fabric js can handle the situation you originally mentioned? ie: have a web page where you scroll an interactive and listening canvas into view, so it completely fills the screen, and yet still have the functionality to scroll the web page past that canvas?

Comment: It is a good point that setting the shape object to listening:false does indeed allow the canvas to be scrollable at the expense of having a static shape. For my purposes this isn't suffice as I am essentially creating an image map and require click events on my objects. So the specific events are scroll the canvas and click the shapes.

Comment: I don't know how fabric treats this but It is the desired behavior for me that when a shape is not draggable and has a click event that the user can scroll past the shape on the ipad. I think if you had many shapes with click events on a canvas you wanted to scroll this would become impractical.

Comment: I also think and have tried something along those lines that it will only become active on the second "touchmove" event as it will take the first touch move to activate all the shapes to be listening.

Comment: www.onlinecakedesign.com -- I'll re-add back in the "piping tool" and the "custom shape tool" within the next day... which will illustrate the 'stop listening' 'start listening' features. The site is still in development but has some of the things you are working on.

Comment: Nice demo, but it still doesn't illustrate scrolling on ipad. I already have a function that can set shape/layer/group attributes. function lockGroups() {
     var groups = stage.find('Group');
     groups.each(function(group) {
      group.setAttrs({draggable: false})
     });

    }

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I like this option though it's better than using one of the many scrolling libraries.  I am able to work around this issue by extending the default Stage class and only executing evt.preventDefault() when I am not on a mobile device. Not sure what bad effects this may cause though so far seem to meet my usage. It would be nice if there were an easier way to modify the default behavior.

```
Kinetic.Global.extend(MyStage, Kinetic.Stage);
function MyStage(mobile, config) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this._initStage(config);
}
MyStage.prototype._touchstart = function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    if (this.mobile) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());

    if(obj && obj.shape) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        this.tapStart = true;
        shape._handleEvent('touchstart', evt);
    }

    /*
                         * init stage drag and drop
                         */
    if(Kinetic.DD && this.attrs.draggable) {
        this._initDrag();
    }
}
MyStage.prototype._touchmove = function(evt) { // Override the default touchmove handler.
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var dd = Kinetic.DD;
    if (this.mobile) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    if(obj && obj.shape) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        shape._handleEvent('touchmove', evt);
    }

    // start drag and drop
    if(dd) {
        dd._startDrag(evt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand the issue, but why not just add 'draggable: true' to the stage

```
// Create a stage instance that is larger than its parent div.
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    draggable: true
});
```

I am using this same method, where my canvas is several times the size of the viewport, and with 'draggable: true' I can scroll around the canvas image.

Comment: The issue isn't so much scrolling the content on the _canvas_, but scrolling a _webpage_ that has a canvas on it. On a mobile device if you have a webpage that contains a canvas, and the user scrolls onto, or zooms so that your canvas fills the screen, they can't 'get off it' again. This is giving me a headache!

Comment: Yes I have seen that same issue. I fixed it in my app by making the canvas portion a popup with a 'close' button. In my case it works. Here's the canvas portion that was causing me problems... (note it's separated here on its own webpage, but you see the problem, this canvas is touch-enabled, and will fill an iPhone 5's screen and then you can't scroll off it.... like you are saying. IO couldnt' find another solution except separating the canvas into its own popup. https://github.com/JSdc/adobe-kuler-clone

Comment: So the only workaround I could come up with, was 'don't use the entire horizontal space' with your Kinetic object. Instead, make it use up (not the whole horizontal space) (see image) (dotted line added for explanation)   https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6971009/2923289/7e311b70-d712-11e3-9c3e-76f7952606fa.jpg    --- if the user clicks on a circle, the class 'unselectable' is applied to the entire panel. If the user releases the circle, 'unselectable' is removed from the panel, so the user can scroll by pressing on the left or right of the dotted line... which is fairly intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with scrolling on iPad/iPhone with a map that I created using KineticJS.

This worked for me: stage.setListening(false);

I found this solution here:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/pull/510